# Find and Delete Outlook Appointment with javascript

Tags: activexobject

I found this code to create an Appointment in Outlook with JavaScript in IE:

```
var objOutlook = new ActiveXObject( "Outlook.Application" );
var olAppointmentItem = 1; //fixed for different properties of outlook object
var objAppointment = objOutlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem);
objAppointment.ReminderSet = true;
objAppointment.Categories = 'Yellow Category';
objAppointment.Subject = "subject";
objAppointment.Location = 'My Location';

objAppointment.Start = "Januar 26, 2018 12:30:00";
var duration = 30;
objAppointment.Duration = duration; 
objAppointment.Save();
```

It works but is it possible to seach an existing Appointment and/or to delete an existing Appointment?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Do you solved this problem?

Comment: Yes you can delete the appointments. First of all, search specfic subject and find it by using Find or Restrict fuction and delete it..